# c# linq union set operations over different store types are currently unsupported for entityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, union

I am using entityframework core and got my select and join query working. I am trying to do a UNION between the 2 select query and visual studio throws "set operation over different store types are currently unsupported"

Here is my code so far

```
var set1 = (this.myDbContent.Table1
            .Join(this.myDbContent.Table2,
              table1 => table1.myId,
              table2 => table2.myId,
              (table1 ,table2) => new {table1 ,table2}
            )
            .Where (
              j => j.table1.myId
            )
            .Select( s =>? new MyViewModel{
               MyID = s.table1.myId
            })
           );

var set2 = (this.myDbContent.Table1
            .Join(this.myDbContent.Table3,
              table1 => table1.myId,
              table3 => table3.myId,
              (table1 ,table2) => new {table1 ,table3}
            )
            .Where (
              j => j.table1.myId
            )
            .Select( s =>? new MyViewModel{
               MyID = s.table1.myId
            })
           );
```

return set1.Union(set2); // here is where the error is thrown

When I hover over each dataSet I see the info

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQuerable for both set1 and set2

Comment: EF and Union is bad story. What are you trying to achieve by these tests? Demystify bad EF Core LINQ translation?

Comment: You could process them in memory: `set1.AsEnumerable().Union(set2.AsEnumerable());`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, and run two queries. Very cool.